# Add padding to row heights in XLSX with Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx

I have some code that outputs an excel file using POI and I want to have it so that my Row heights have a bit more space than the automatic heights that get set if I do nothing.

Currently i get a row using `sheet.createRow(rowNumber)` and then I don't set the height at all, and excel / POI just seems to take care of that.

I now want to add a buffer to the automatically set heights, (say 20px) but I cant see a way to do this, when I add my cells it doesn't seem to actually set the height property of the row automatically, so I can't do `row.setHeight(row.getHeight()+20)` because getHeight just returns the default height, and so all my Rows end up the same height, instead of the auto height + 20.

Similarly if i set the Default height of the sheet it doesn't bother automatically working out heights for anything that needs to be bigger than the default.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is no margin padding on row height in `Excel` sheets. And the row height is either auto, which means not set but content dependent, or is set in points (pt). So there is not a way to fulfill your requirement. Hint: If you get a requirement, first try fulfilling it using `Excel`'s GUI. If that is not possible, then also `apache poi` will not be able to fulfill it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you're using the right API but as Axel Ritcher pointed out, there is no concept of padding for a cell. The only problem is that `20` is such a tiny value that you can't see any notable difference. You can try something like:

```java
row.setHeight((short)(row.getHeight() * 2));
```